# Remove item from list of dictionaries based on values in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list
`items_to_delete = [(69, 70), (84, 88)]`

and I want to remove all items from a list of dictionaries where the `start` and `end` values are equal to the tuples in the `items_to_delete` list.

```
input_list = 
[{'name': 'John', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 69, 'end': 70}, 
 {'name': 'Sara', 'gender': 'female', 'start': 75, 'end': 80},  
 {'name': 'George', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 84, 'end': 88},
 {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 98, 'end': 101}]
```

Expected output is:

```
[{'name': 'Sara', 'gender': 'female', 'start': 75, 'end': 80},
 {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 98, 'end': 101}]
```

What I have done so far:

```
res = [dict_ent for dict_ent in input_list for item in items_to_delete if not (dict_ent['start']==item[0] and dict_ent['end']==item[1])]
```

but it has the dictionaries that I don't want x1 and the dictionaries that I want x2.

How can I achieve the desired result using list comprehension?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because of the inner loop. For example, when dict_ent=first dictionary element and item=(69,70), the condition is false and not stored in res. However, in the next iteration of the inner loop, when the value of item changes to (84,88), the condition is satisfied, and the dict is stored in res. Similarly, this condition is satisfied twice for the second dictionary element due to the inner loop, so it is stored twice. You can use a break statement by expanding the for loop to fix this.

```
items_to_delete = [(69, 70), (84, 88)]
input_list = [{'name': 'John', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 69, 'end': 70}, 
 {'name': 'Sara', 'gender': 'female', 'start': 75, 'end': 80},  
 {'name': 'George', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 84, 'end': 88},
 {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 98, 'end': 101}]
res=[]
for i in input_list:
    for j in items_to_delete:
        if i['start']==j[0] and i['end']==j[1]:
            break
    else:
        res.append(i)
for i in res:
    for j in i:
        print(j,i[j])
```

If you want to use list comprehension to achieve this, you can do the following:

```
items_to_delete = [(69, 70), (84, 88)]
input_list = [{'name': 'John', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 69, 'end': 70},  {'name': 'Sara', 'gender': 'female', 'start': 75, 'end': 80},   {'name': 'George', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 84, 'end': 88}, {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 98, 'end': 101}]
res = [i for i in input_list if not any((i['start'], i['end']) == j for j in items_to_delete)]

for i in res:
    for j in i:
        print(j, i[j])
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a helper function, which will determine whether the item should be preserved or not.

```py
def is_viable_item(item, forbidden):
    return ((item.get("start"), item.get("end")) in forbidden) is False

filtered_input = [item for item in input_list if is_viable_item(item, items_to_delete)]
```

Side notes:

- you can skip the helper function and move its logic to the comprehension, but it's getting less readable that way

```py
filtered_input = [item for item in input_list if ((item.get("start"), item.get("end")) in items_to_delete) is False]
```

- you can use functools (partial) to freeze the 2nd argument of the helper function

Comment: items to delete should probably be a set, also (especially if you go to the effort of using partial), for big-O reasons.

Comment: I didn't change items to delete since the OP didn't mention how else is he using that, maybe he needs access by index. Either way it's not question related imho.

Comment: @KellyBundy fair point, forgot the parenthesis, should be fine now.

Comment: Better just use the `not in` operator instead of `in` and the extra comparison to `False`...

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using the built-in [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter):

```
from operator import itemgetter

items_to_delete = [(69, 70), (84, 88)]
input_list = [
    {'name': 'John', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 69, 'end': 70},
    {'name': 'Sara', 'gender': 'female', 'start': 75, 'end': 80},
    {'name': 'George', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 84, 'end': 88},
    {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 98, 'end': 101}
]

it = itemgetter("start", "end")
new_list = [d for d in input_list if it(d) not in items_to_delete]

for i in new_list:
    print(i)

# output:
# {'name': 'Sara', 'gender': 'female', 'start': 75, 'end': 80}
# {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 98, 'end': 101}
```

You can do something similar using [`itertools.filterfalse`](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse)

```
from itertools import filterfalse

items_to_delete = [(69, 70), (84, 88)]
input_list = [
    {'name': 'John', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 69, 'end': 70},
    {'name': 'Sara', 'gender': 'female', 'start': 75, 'end': 80},
    {'name': 'George', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 84, 'end': 88},
    {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 98, 'end': 101}
]

new_list = filterfalse(lambda x: (x["start"], x["end"]) in items_to_delete, input_list)

for i in new_list:
    print(i)

# output:
# {'name': 'Sara', 'gender': 'female', 'start': 75, 'end': 80}
# {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 98, 'end': 101}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Avoid an explicit inner loop

Let the Python `in` operator do that work for you, as it will be less prone to error than writing an inner loop.

```
input_list = [
 {'name': 'John', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 69, 'end': 70}, 
 {'name': 'Sara', 'gender': 'female', 'start': 75, 'end': 80},  
 {'name': 'George', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 84, 'end': 88},
 {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 98, 'end': 101}
]

items_to_delete = [(69, 70), (84, 88)]

res = [ dict_ent for dict_ent in input_list  if (dict_ent['start'],dict_ent['end']) not in items_to_delete ]

print(res)
```

Result:

```
[
 {'name': 'Sara', 'gender': 'female', 'start': 75, 'end': 80}, 
 {'name': 'James', 'gender': 'male', 'start': 98, 'end': 101}
]
```